# How can I prevent the user to be logged in automatically in my web application after loging out using Microsoft azure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure

I'm developing a web which uses the microsoft account to login/out the user.
I have to fix an issue related to the Microsoft azure authentication. Right now, when the user clicks on the sign out button, the user logs out, but he/she is automatically logged in into the web that I'm developing.
I don't want this behaviour. I want the user to be redirect to the web and only if the user clicks on the sign in button, he/she is logged in in the web. I don't know how to prevent the fact that the user is signed is automatically.
picture

[image]
I have tried other solutions, but always get the same behaviour.

I have this file:

```
const branchUrl = new RegExp(/\/BUY-\d{4}/).exec(window.location.pathname)?.[0] ?? '';

const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_TENANT_ID}`,
    clientId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_CLIENT_ID}`,
    redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}${branchUrl}`,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: `${window.location.origin}${branchUrl}`,
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false, 
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  },
};

const msalLoginRequest: PopupRequest = {
  scopes: [
    'User.Read',
  ],
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

if (accounts.length > 0) {
  msalInstance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);
}

msalInstance.addEventCallback((event: EventMessage) => {
  if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && event.payload) {
    const payload = event.payload as AuthenticationResult;
    const account = payload.account;
    msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
  }
});

export const msalService = {
  msalInstance,
  msalLoginRequest,
};
```

Component with the logic

```
export const Header = ({ styleNumber, setStyleNumber, generalQuery, setGeneralQuery }: HeaderProps): ReactElement => {

  const { login } = useContext(AuthorizationContext);
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  const account = useAccount(accounts[0] || {});

  const handleOnSignIn = (): void =>{
    login();
  };



  const handleSignOut = (): void => {
    instance.logoutRedirect({
      account,
    }).then(() => {
    })
.catch((error) => {
      // Handle logout error if needed
      console.error('Logout error:', error);
    });
  };

  return (
        <Box
          sx={{
            height: '24px',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            paddingLeft: 10,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        >
          {isAuthenticated ? (
            <Box
              sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <UserInfo />
              <Button key="signOut-button" size="large" sx={{ marginLeft: 2 }} onClick= 
               {handleSignOut}>
                Sign Out
              </Button>
              <Button component="label" variant="contained" startIcon={<PlusIcon />} sx={{ 
                  marginLeft: 2 }} onClick={handleCreateCertificate}>
                Create a new certificate
              </Button>
            </Box>
        ) : (
          <Button key="signIn-button" size="large" sx={{ marginLeft: 2 }} onClick= 
             {handleOnSignIn}>
            Sign In
          </Button>
        )}
      </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: When you are using OAuth to authorize users within your app, then "logging out" is only supposed to log them out of your app (invalidating the current access token), not out of the login provider's site itself. That is intentional, Facebook for example handles it the same way. (Only if the user logged in to Facebook _during_ the process of logging in to the customer app, the logout within the app will also log them out of Facebook itself.)

Comment: @CBroe so how can I solve this issue? I'm new to this.

Comment: I don't think there _is_ anything to solve here. Your expectation simply does not match up with how this actually works.

Comment: @CBroe there must be something to change somewhere in code, so that the user can login or log out as desired. Hope someone can give an idea.

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually mean by "the web" here? Are you talking about the web frontend of _your_ app, or are you talking about the Microsoft Azure site where the user goes to grant your app permission?

Comment: @CBroe I'm referring to the web that I'm developing. So in the front, the user has one button the sign in, and after the user logs in , he/she has to sing out button. I've uploaded a picture in my post.

Comment: Okay, so not logout of the Azure service itself then. That users are getting logged-in automatically on a repeat visit, is a feature usually _wanted_ with OAuth login. Whether there is a way to prevent it, depends on your specific login provider. I know that Facebook has an option for that in their implementation, but I don't know any details about Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and successfully signed in/signed out.

**Code :**

***msalService.js :***

```js
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>`,
    clientId: "<client_id>",
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  },
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const msalLoginRequest = {
  scopes: ['User.Read'],
};

const logout = () => {
  const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
  if (accounts.length > 0) {
    msalInstance.logoutRedirect({
      account: accounts[0], 
    });
  }
};

export { msalInstance, msalLoginRequest, logout };
```

***Header.js :***

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { logout } from '../services/msalService';

const Header = () => {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    instance.logoutRedirect({ account: accounts[0] });
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      {accounts.length > 0 ? (
        <Box>
          <p>Welcome, {accounts[0].name}</p>
          <Button onClick={handleSignOut}>Sign Out</Button>
        </Box>
      ) : (
        <Button onClick={() => instance.loginPopup()}>Sign In</Button>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I added the following **URL** to the registered app as a **Single-page application**:

> http://localhost:3000

[image]

**Output :**

It ran successfully, as shown below:

[image]

**Output at browser :**

I accessed the following page with the output URL. Next, I clicked the **SIGN IN** button, chose my account for signing in, and saw this:

[image]

Afterward, I got to this page and clicked on the **SIGN OUT** button to sign out:

[image]

Then, I selected my account for signing out:

[image]

I successfully signed out, as shown below:

[image]

Finally, I was redirected to the **SIGN IN** page:

[image]